# How to export Tally ledger opening and cloing balance with voucher details?

Tags: java, soap, tally

I am trying to get Tally Erp 9 Ledger voucher through post XML Request, everything is working fine except opening and closing balance. Please guide me to get both balance amount.

```
**XML Request:**

<ENVELOPE>
  <HEADER>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>
  </HEADER>
  <BODY>
    <EXPORTDATA>
      <REQUESTDESC>
        <STATICVARIABLES>
          <SVFROMDATE>20190401</SVFROMDATE>
          <SVTODATE>20190901</SVTODATE>
          <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
          <LEDGERNAME>Tally Ledger Name</LEDGERNAME>
        </STATICVARIABLES>
        <REPORTNAME>Ledger Vouchers</REPORTNAME>
      </REQUESTDESC>
    </EXPORTDATA>
  </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>

**XML Response:**

<ENVELOPE>
    <DSPVCHDATE>1-9-2019</DSPVCHDATE>
    <DSPVCHLEDACCOUNT>PNB Bank A/C 9900</DSPVCHLEDACCOUNT>
    <DSPVCHTYPE>Pymt</DSPVCHTYPE>
    <DSPVCHDRAMT>-1500000.00</DSPVCHDRAMT>
    <DSPVCHCRAMT></DSPVCHCRAMT>
    <DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>(No. :14)</DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>
    <DSPVCHDATE>1-9-2019</DSPVCHDATE>
    <DSPVCHLEDACCOUNT>PNB Bank A/C 9900</DSPVCHLEDACCOUNT>
    <DSPVCHTYPE>Pymt</DSPVCHTYPE>
    <DSPVCHDRAMT>-1000.00</DSPVCHDRAMT>
    <DSPVCHCRAMT></DSPVCHCRAMT>
    <DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>(No. :17)</DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>
    <DSPVCHDATE>1-9-2019</DSPVCHDATE>
    <DSPVCHLEDACCOUNT>PNB Bank A/C 9900</DSPVCHLEDACCOUNT>
    <DSPVCHTYPE>Pymt</DSPVCHTYPE>
    <DSPVCHDRAMT>-1000.00</DSPVCHDRAMT>
    <DSPVCHCRAMT></DSPVCHCRAMT>
    <DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>(No. :18)</DSPEXPLVCHNUMBER>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Comment: is there any way to get all entries separated by some tag ? to parse it as array?

Answer (score 1):

Add the below tag under LEDGERNAME tag

```
<LEDGERNAME>THE LEDGER NAME</LEDGERNAME>
<SHOWRUNBALANCE>YES</SHOWRUNBALANCE>
```

Note - This will give the closing balance only. Not the opening balance. For the opening balance, **get the value from the tag DSPVCHLEDBALANCE and subtract the sum of all the values from the DSPVCHDRAMT**.

*Warning - these return negative numbers (notice in your XML response), so don't forget to get the absolute value.*

The other way to get opening and closing balance in one go is to query the Ledger directly rather than the "Ledger Vouchers" report -

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>OBJECT</TYPE>
        <SUBTYPE>Ledger</SUBTYPE>
        <ID TYPE="Name">Tally Ledger Name</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>YOUR COMPANY NAME</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <FETCHLIST>
                <FETCH>OPENINGBALANCE</FETCH>
                <FETCH>CLOSINGBALANCE</FETCH>
            </FETCHLIST>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```